# Is there a term for "one who sees people in terms of their 'race/ethnicity', but isn't hateful"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm searching for an English word (or short phrase) that means "one who sees people in terms of their 'race/ethnicity', but isn't hateful".

I've searched for such a term, but haven't found one.

Comment: Is this about political correctness? A PC person sees people in terms of race or ethnicity all the time without being hateful about it, but it's not exclusively about that?

Comment: I think that [Cultural diversity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_diversity) is neutral. However, a more general term could be minority, or [minority groups](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minority_group) which is used in sociology and in politics.

Comment: @Cerberus No, didn't even cross my mind.

Comment: Hyperfocused on race, or overly race-aware, hung up about race, all about race, a labeler.

Comment: @aparente001 That's the idea.  Especially the first three phrases.

Comment: In what sense. *Observant*? Why should seeing their race be any different than seeing anything else? Of if race *is* relevant—how is it relevant?

Comment: Also, harps on race, superficial, only sees skin deep.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, there is no commonly used term, since most English speakers have realized that racial stereotyping is bad (if not hateful). Thus, *racist*, with its negative connotation is the word.

However, some find it useful to differentiate the outmoded concept of *racialism*.

> **racialism**
>
> : a theory that race determines human traits and capacities

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/racialism

> In 1903, W. E. B. Du Bois said that racialism is the philosophical position that races existed, and that collective differences existed among such categories, the races.[citation needed] He further stated that racism required advancing the argument that one race is superior to other races of human beings. In In My Father’s House (1992), Kwame Anthony Appiah summarized Du Bois's philosophical stance that racialism is value-neutral term and that racism is a value-charged term.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racialism

Answer (score 0):

**demographer**

> An expert in the study of statistics relating to the changing
>   structure of human populations.

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/demographer)